# problem with pagination using kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'm building a rails app using rails geocoder gem to search the nearby locations given a zip and kaminari to paginate the search results. All went well until I tried using per(2) method to display 2 results per page, then some of the query results got lost. The per method worked fine when used without geocoder filter. The following is my code in the controller:

```
if params[:search].present?
    @users=User.near(params[:search], 5).order(:id).page(params[:page]).per(2)


else

    @users = User.order(:id).page(params[:page]).per(2)
end
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light into this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to pass the limit on your model? like `paginates_per 2`

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work..

Comment: Just fixed it per denysonique's comment on replacing length with count in total_count at github denysonique/kaminari. Thanks so much denysonique!!

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you fixed it? Link?

Comment: Found it - https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/160

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem was fixed in kaminari 0.13.0 gem. Could you try the newest gem?